# Derivation of the solution of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I was reading a proof from Evans' book of partial differential equations, until I got stuck.

[image]

[image]

Until $(6)$ everything is clear, but then he assumes that $v$ is radial and then the ODE completely changes shape. Furthermore, I don't get the successive passages, until $(7)$. Is there anyone that can explain them to me? It would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this "guess" is the fact that the laplacian $\Delta$ is rotation invariant, i.e. $\Delta u(x)=\Delta u(Tx)$ for any rotation $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, so one can seek a radial (or rotation invariant) solution. He then lets $v(y)=w(|y|)$ and plugs this into the PDE, which reduces to the ODE, now we are at the following part 
$$r^{n-1}w'+\frac{1}{2}r^nw=a.$$
We now assume $\lim_{r\to\infty}w'=\lim_{r\to\infty}w=0$, this condition just ensures nice behaviour of the solution at infinity, but if we take this limit in the above equation we see that we must have $a=0$ for this to be true.

Now by rearranging we have a nice easy to solve ODE, 
$$\frac{w'}{w}=-\frac{1}{2}r.$$

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I've solved everything by reviewing the properties of the laplacian of a radial function!

Comment: No problem, glad you have solved it :)